# Page Freezes on iOS Loading Query

Tags: php, javascript, ios, css

I have a client site that has two specific CSS and JS files, one for desktops and one for iOS devices:

```
<?php if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPhone') || strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPod') || strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPad')) 
    {
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://example.com/style.mobile.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" href="http://example.com/js/scripts.mobile.js"></script>';
    }else{
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://example.com/style.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" href="http://example.com/js/scripts.js"></script>';
    } 
?>
```

If I load either CSS/JS set, the site works just as it should. If I add this IF statement, the site hangs and never loads.

Even more puzzling, is that I'm using the exact same IF statement to load different elements on the same page and it works just as it should. Is there something about using it in the header, or with JS that I'm unaware of?

Or, is there a better, more bulletproof way to go about this?

Thanks,

ty

Comment: Try stylemobile.css instead of style.mobile.css and let me know then (although i m not very sure but may be the extension is what actually causing it to take time) do the same for script file.

Comment: The only error logs I'm getting are for the javascripts that are written into the page that refer to the script that's supposed to load. Swapnesh's suggestion actually worked. I'm curious as to why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swapnesh's suggestion actually worked. I'd really like to understand why.